# How can set variable names in an "Array" of variables in GEKKO

Tags: gekko

I have a (n x p) matrix of FV parameters in a MINLP problem.

When I define the FV's using list comprehension as below, I end up getting an in feasibility

```
for i in range(n):
    test[i] = [m.FV(lb=0, ub=1, integer=True, name="example) for j in range(p)]
```

On the other hand, when I use an array I do get a solution quickly.

```
for i in range(n):
   test[i] = m.Array(m.FV, p, lb=0, ub=1, integer=True)
```

I would like to add variable names to my FV's so that I can quickly troubleshoot and select the parameters in the optimal solution. This is fairly straight forward with the list comprehension, but with the array my only option seems to make duplicate names, which isn't too useful.

Comment: There isn't currently a way to rename a variable once it is declared. In general, you don't need to name the internal variable name unless you need more readable files in the run folder `m.path` or `m.open_folder()`. Renaming variables isn't likely the issue with your problem. You'll see the same fast solution if you remove `integer=True` from `test[i] = m.Array(m.FV, p, lb=0, ub=1, integer=True)`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that renaming the variable as `example` or some other name is causing the `test` variable to no longer be an integer type. The underlying APMonitor engine recognizes variables that start with `int` as integer type. Changing to something else makes it so the solver is not required to find an integer solution and it is successful at finding a non-integer solution.

It is generally much easier to solve a problem as a continuous versus integer problem. I recommend initializing with:

```py
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solver_options = ['minlp_as_nlp 1']
m.solve()
```

and then solve again with to get an integer solution (if possible):

```py
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solver_options = ['minlp_as_nlp 0']
m.solve()
```

If it fails on the second solve then there is likely no integer solution or else the solver failed to converge in the number of required iterations. You can increase the iterations with:

```py
m.options.MAX_ITER=1000
```

If it is having a hard time finding an integer solution then try adding an additional option to do a depth-first search:

```py
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solver_options = ['minlp_as_nlp 0', \
                    'minlp_branch_method 1']
m.options.MAX_ITER=1000
m.solve()
```

There is more information on setting solver options in Gekko: [How to set solver options (such as error tolerance) in Python Gekko?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59052723/how-to-set-solver-options-such-as-error-tolerance-in-python-gekko) and more information on the [solver options](https://apopt.com/download.php).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a work around where I can make my name include 'int'?

Comment: There isn't a work-around in Gekko to rename variables. There are many places where that variable name is added in the internals of how Gekko works. You can see how that all works in GK_Operators.py, gekko.py, and other source files in the install directory: `/Lib/site-packages/gekko/`. Again, naming variables is only cosmetic and doesn't change the optimization results (unless switching from integer to continuous variables with the name change). In general, it is better to let Gekko handle the internal naming to avoid things like name conflicts.